# Machine Learning algorithms based on "structural risk minimization"?

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

Which machine learning algorithms (besides SVM's) use the principle of [structural risk minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_risk_minimization)?

Comment: What is an algo?

Comment: algo = algorithm ;)

Comment: please use complete words.

Comment: ok..just didn't wanna make the title too long

Comment: As far as I can tell SRM is nothing but good old [regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29), which is used absolutely everywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The structural risk minimization principle is a principle that is at least partly 'used' in all machine learning methods, since overfitting is often to be taken into account: reducing the complexity of the model is (supposedly and in practice) a good way to limit overfitting.

- SVMs explicitly have a parameter for the complexity (the dimension of the [feature space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_space), or even the kernel function) and it's necessary because increasing the complexity is a part of the learning algorithm.
- Neuronal networks also have a easy indicator of their complexity (number of 'cells') and is part of the associated learning algorithm.
- Without this principle [grammar inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_induction) would be both stupid and perfect grammar is the list of all possible words, so every non-trivial algorithm at least acknowledges this principle.
- Decision trees have [their own notion of entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_in_decision_trees).
- [Clusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) can be simply counted or [kind of 'use' the principle intrinsically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) or [have a fixed number of clusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and in that case you apply the principle at a higher level.

To be perfectly honest I don't really know about what happens in genetic programming but they don't have an intrinsic notion of complexity.

I don't know well [Inductive logic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_logic_programming) but it doesn't seem to scale very well to this principle.

Comment: Do you know of any learning algorithm that is even more powerful and less prone to overfitting than SVM? Or maybe a technique to improve standard SVM?

Comment: @user2278 if by 'powerful' you mean 'efficient' then SVMs are pretty great and there is *a lot* of [research](http://www.dblp.org/search/#query=support+vector+machine) about it and [tools](http://www.support-vector-machines.org/SVM_soft.html) using it. But of course, it depends on your problem.

Comment: Well, I'd like to use SVM in the financial markets, and there are actually quite a few papers dedicated to this topic (using SVM for stock prediction, etc...). Is there an algorithm that would be better suited for that purpose (especially since financial time-series are so "noisy")?

Comment: @user2278 You better use the papers. I'm not an expert. (I would not be surprised SVMs are the best for that. Also they behave well wrt. noise)